# How to replace html text with php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm having trouble replacing the text in a `<a>` tag on my Wordpress site. What I'm wanting to do:

- If $funded == $goal, change the text in the  tag to "Fully Funded" and have it grayed out and not clickable.

Here is the code I have thus far:

PHP:

```
$goal = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Adopt a Planter: Funding Goal', true);                
$funded = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Adopt a Planter: Funding Progress', true);
```

html:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Adopt a Planter: Link to Cart', true); ?>"class="adopt-btn">Change This Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but I hope this helps.

```
<?php
$goal = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Adopt a Planter: Funding Goal', true);                
$funded = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Adopt a Planter: Funding Progress', true);

if ($goal == $funded){ ?>
    <a name="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Adopt a Planter: Link to Cart', true); ?>"class="adopt-btn"><u style="color:gray;">Fully Funded</u></a> 
<?php }else{ ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Adopt a Planter: Link to Cart', true); ?>"class="adopt-btn">Change This Text</a>
<?php } ?>
<!-- html from here -->
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was asking! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if youre just changing the text that says "Change This Text", then you can put this in that place:

```
<?php 
    if ($funded == $goal) { echo ('Fully Funded'); }
    else { echo ('Change This Text'); }
?>
```

that is, assuming that you defined $goal and $funded somewhere that is accessible to the html page

Comment: How would I attach the changed text to the <a> tag?

Comment: @JacobCarpenter, inside it: <a href="..." whatever classes here><?php my code here;?></a>

Answer (score 0):

You can predefine your variable and use one IF() clause.

```
$status="Not funded";//for ex
if($goal==$funded){
$status="Fully Funded";
}
<a href="..." class="..."><?php echo $status;?></a>
```